# Concatenate function name with id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, concatenation

What actually i want to do is onclick="openModal@options.Id();"

i.e I want to call function like openModal1(), openModal2(), openModal3() on onclick.

I want to concatenate optionId with function name on onclick. I tried `winows['string'+id]()` but it did work for me.

This is the code i did.

```
<span>
@options.Name - <a href="#" onclick="window['openModal' +@options.Id]();" class="hover-shadow cursor">Screen Shot</a>
</span>
```

Comment: will you include your openModal functions? It's better if you only have 1 open modal but yourr function call has a parameter which indicates which modal to open.

Comment: Yes, I had followed this link. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp and there are 10 modals in my page with 10 openModai modal functions. with name line openModal1(), openModal2() and so on.

Comment: please include 1 open modal code or your actual html. This will help us create a script specific for your elements